# Checking if string is empty in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Java, we've always been reminded to use `myString.isEmpty()` to check whether a String is empty. In Kotlin however, I find that you can use either `myString == ""` or `myString.isEmpty()` or even `myString.isBlank()`.

Are there any guidelines/recommendations on this? Or is it simply "anything that rocks your boat"?

Thanks in advance for feeding my curiosity. :D

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Don't use `myString == ""`, in java this would be `myString.equals("")` which also isn't recommended.

`isBlank` is not the same as `isEmpty` and it really depends on your use-case.

`isBlank` checks that a char sequence has a 0 length or that all indices are white space. `isEmpty` only checks that the char sequence length is 0.

```
/**
 * Returns `true` if this string is empty or consists solely of whitespace characters.
 */
public fun CharSequence.isBlank(): Boolean = length == 0 || indices.all { this[it].isWhitespace() }


/**
 * Returns `true` if this char sequence is empty (contains no characters).
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun CharSequence.isEmpty(): Boolean = length == 0
```

Comment: Since Kotlin 1.3, there's even a new extension function available which is `ifBlank` and it allows you to assign a default string if your main value is empty

Answer (score 38):

For `String?` (nullable String) datatype, I use `.isNullOrBlank()`

For `String`, I use `.isBlank()`

Why? Because most of the time, I do not want to allow Strings with whitespace (and `.isBlank()` checks whitespace as well as empty String). If you don't care about whitespace, use `.isNullorEmpty()` and `.isEmpty()` for `String?` and `String`, respectively.

Comment: I've also thought of always using isBlank(), but did you know that passwords could actually be just spaces? Of course, that depends on what you'd allow. Thanks for the reminder on nullable String! Here's an invisible upvote. :D

Comment: Depends on the situation, but I would assume that an only blank space password would be disallowed by most websites/backends. Then again, I've never tried it! But +1 for extreme edge cases

Comment: String can be null, so i always choose ~string.isNullOrBlank()

Answer (score 12):

Use `isEmpty` when you want to test that a String is exactly equal to the empty string `""`.

Use `isBlank` when you want to test that a String is empty or only consists of whitespace (`""`, `"   "`).

Avoid using `== ""`.

Answer (score 9):

There are two methods available in Kotlin.

1. isNullOrBlank()
2. isNullOrEmpty()

And the difference is:

```kotlin
data = " " // this is a text with blank space 
 
println(data.isNullOrBlank()?.toString())  //true
println(data.isNullOrEmpty()?.toString())  //false
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `isNullOrBlank()` to check is a string is null or empty. This method considers spaces only strings to be empty.

Here is a usage example:

```
val s: String? = null
println(s.isNullOrBlank())
val s1: String? = ""
println(s1.isNullOrBlank())
val s2: String? = "     "
println(s2.isNullOrBlank())
val s3: String? = "  a "
println(s3.isNullOrBlank())
```

The output of this snippet is:

```
true
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned in the comments, you can use `ifBlank`, like so:

```kotlin
fun getSomeValue(): String {
  // ...
  val foo = someCall()
  return foo.ifBlank { "some-default" }
}
```

Documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/if-blank.html