# How to validate class String property is not empty in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, validation

Given:

```
class JWTToken(val token: String) {
// ...
var email: String = jwt.claims["email"]?.asString()?: 
        throw Exception("null email")

}
```

The exception is thrown if `wt.claims["email"]` is null, but not if the is string empty.

How can the check for the empty string be concisely added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin's require built-in would be a good candidate here:

```kotlin
val aNullableOrBlankValue: String? = "..."

class JWTToken(val token: String) {
    var email: String = aNullableOrBlankValue
        .let { requireNotNull(it) { "Email should not be null..." } }
        .apply { require(isNotBlank()) { "Email should not be blank..." } }
}
```

The methods [`require`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) and [`requireNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require-not-null.html) will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the value is false for `require`, or null for `requireNotNull`.

Another concise way to write this would be:

```kotlin
var email2: String = aNullableOrBlankValue
        .apply { require(!isNullOrBlank()) { "Email should not be blank or null..." } }!!
```

Albeit less readable (notice the `!!`), and error not as clear.

Do note that `isBlank` is not the same as `isEmpty` and it really depends on your use-case. (In your case, `isBlank` is more appropriate as emails should not be blank)

> `isBlank` checks that a char sequence has a 0 length or that all indices are white space. `isEmpty` only checks that the char sequence length is 0.

See: [stackoverflow.com/a/45337014/5037430](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45337014/5037430) for further detalis.

Comment: You don't need `!!` because `isNullOrBlank` has a contract that causes it to be smart cast to not-null.

Comment: Hmm for which Kotlin version? It seems that the `apply` scoped function negate the smart cast? (Jetbrains IDE complaining) Perhaps my IDE config is messed up.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I guess smart casting doesn't work in that case. If you use `.let { require(!it.isNullOrBlank(); it }`, then it allows it. I guess since the return type is already determined *before* the code inside the apply/let lambda, the contract doesn't help narrow it down.

Comment: Ah I see, cool, thanks for that! (Always wondered why it doesn't smart cast there)

Comment: Looks like this might be fixed in Kotlin 2.0: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28806 This is subtly different, since it's about the smart cast working internally in the lambda, but I think it might also apply. But this more applicable YouTrack issue has not been updated, so I'm not sure. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48894/Allow-smartcast-after-return-from-called-in-place-lambda

Comment: Cool, I just found this relevant blog too: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2023/02/k2-kotlin-2-0/